# powershell New-AzAppServicePlan

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-app-service-plans

im trying to configure a powershell script to deploy new-azAppServicePlan with zone redundancy, which Im failiing to get right.
it can be done in cli but i cannot figure it out using powershell.

```
##Part 1 - Create a new Linux App Service Plan

$ResourceGroupName = "-sandbox-ASE"
$ServicePlanName = "-service-plan01"
$location = "southafricanorth"

New-AzAppServicePlan `
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
-Name $ServicePlanName `
-Location $location `
--Tier "PremiumV3" `
-NumberofWorkers 1 `
-WorkerSize "Small" `
-Linux `
-ZoneRedundant $true
```

ive tried:
-ZoneRedundant $true
and
-Zone 1, 2, 3

Comment: The Zone parameter is not available in the **New-AzResource** and **New-AzAppServicePlan**, refer the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azappserviceplan?view=azps-11.0.0) for more details

Comment: Was there an error message? `New-AzAppServicePlan: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ZoneRedundant'.`

Comment: Yes. I tried both  zone and ZoneRedunt.

Comment: @allen Visser - In the above cmdlet you are passing the Tier property with `--Tier` instead of `-Tier` which is not supported. Also, if you want to deploy app service plan with zone redundant you need to use the AzCLI cmdlet az appservice plan create cmdlet which has `--zone-redundant` property refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-create) for more information about cmdlet supported properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above cmdlet you are passing the Tier property with `--Tier` instead of `-Tier` which is not supported.

Also, if you want to deploy app service plan with zone redundant you need to use the AzCLI cmdlet az appservice plan create cmdlet which has `--zone-redundant` property.

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-create) for more information about cmdlet supported properties